# Change active C# .NET project configuration and platform in VSCode

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio we have this:
[image]

While in VSCode, configuration seems always to be 'DEBUG' while the platform is 'AnyCPU'.
Intellisense simply disregards the codes inside the block:

```
#if !DEBUG
...
#endif
```

Comment: Yeah, the `!` is a negative sign, so that code block only will be include when it is **not** in Debug mode

Comment: Thanks for reply. Well, DEBUG is an example, in visual studio, if you change active profile to release, it will start to recognize codes in the block. And usually our project has more profiles other than debug and release, and some code does depend on constants defined in profile at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there isn't a way to do this in the UI (see [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/vscode-csharp/issues/5643)).

For now, this can be done by specifying the configuration in `.vscode/tasks.json`:

```json
//...
"tasks": [
{
  "label": "build",
  "command": "dotnet",
  "type": "process",
  "args": [
    "build",
    //...
    // Add the next two lines
    "--configuration",
    "Release"  // <--- This is the active configuration.
   ],
//...
}
```

Then, add property groups that define the pre-compilation constants `DEBUG` and `RELEASE`, according to the configuration:

In file `ProjectName.csproj`:

```xml
<Project>
<!-- ... -->

  <PropertyGroup Condition="$(Configuration.Contains(Debug))">
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="$(Configuration.Contains(Release))">
    <DefineConstants>RELEASE</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>

<!-- ... -->
</Project>
```